# Can Django support symbolic link models.py and migrations directory?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I have 3 django projects and one database. I want to share database from each apps. So, I made database from app3 and made symbolic links of models.py and migrations directory from app1 and app2.

I use only app3 when I want to migrate database. This seems to work well.
I can also make superuser from app3.

But when I want to create superuser(manage.py createsuperuser) from app1 and app2, I got the following error.

```
django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration remoshin_user_sys.0004_auto_20170827_2351 dependencies reference nonexistent parent node ('remoshin_manager_sys', '0003_auto_20170827_2349')
```

I want to know my approach can work when 3 apps share one database.
Would you help me please?

Add directory tree.

app1(project)

- app1

- app1_sys

- models.py (symbolic link)

- migrations (symbolic link)

app2(project)

- app2

- app2_sys

- models.py (symbolic link)

- migrations (symbolic link)

app3(project)

- app3

- app3_sys

- models.py (NOT symbolic link)

- migrations (NOT symbolic link)

Comment: In Django terminology **project** and **app** are different terms. A **project** may contain one or many **apps**.  Usually one database is used per **project**, although there are many other possibilities. Maybe you can post a tree of your working directory.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I have 3 projects, not 3 apps in one project. I add a directory tree of my project. Please give me an advice.

Comment: I've never ever seen this design pattern. Maybe I just lack experience and this is something great. Basing on my knowledge and experience I'd go with class inheritance: concrete, abstract or proxy.

Comment: What are exactly your requirements and needs? Can you explain what do you want to achieve? I'm completely confused with your approach.

Comment: Thank you for reply. My app1 is to give restful api for smartphone users. My app2 is a web site for service provider to give a service to smartphone user. And my app3 is for system administrator. Only app3 can run migrations because app3 is for system administrator. But I want to share all data from the database. That is my requirement.

Comment: Can you explain why do you need 3 different projects for this? What hinders you to have 3 apps in one project, which is the most logical thing. I have the impression that you are overcomplicating some very basic things.

Comment: Thank you for replay. At first I tried to make 3 apps in one project. But something didn't work. Unfortunately, I forgot what it was. All I remember is I couldn't made 3 different user authentication system in one project. Especially, it was hard that I have only one settings.py. In my app, enduser, service provider and system administrator need their own user authentication system. I thought I may make these authentication system easy more one project. How do you think this? Do you think I should make each apps in one project?

Comment: In this particular case you should definitely put all your apps in one project. You can create custom authentication, that shouldn't be an unsolvable problem for you.

Comment: Thank you for an advice. I will re-think about this system in one project. But I have no idea 2 things. One is that how can I create superuser of each your(enduser, service provider, system administrator) using one manage.py and python environment? I don't want to merge their data into one table. Second, how can I write AUTH_USER_MODEL in settings.py, I have 3 custom authentication models? If they are all clear, I can go with one project.

Comment: I can't give you an exact solution from here, but you can subclass your authentication models from a parent user model.

Comment: Thank you for your kindness advice. I tried to check information about the subclass of authentication model, but I couldn't get anything. Could you give me some information site or information  please?